# How do you get edge flow information from mesh

Tags: mesh

Below there are two identical meshes, however the first one has edges moving in random directions, the second one has edges moving in a orderly, uniform fashion (edge flow).

[image]

i want to be able to make a mesh with uniform edges (good edge flow) from a mesh with bad edge flow.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more background to your question.

Comment: Please narrow down the question with more detail on what you are looking to achieve. It might also help to describe what information you already have about the mesh, perhaps with an example.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but what defines "good topology" vs "bad topology"? Are you after the effectiveness of each polygon, or how regular the mesh is?

Comment: good topology is a low polygon mesh with faces in the right location such that when animated the mesh deforms properly. i want to generate a low poly mesh FROM the high poly mesh with good topology

Comment: "Suitable for animation" is much more meaningful than "good", and different things can be good in different contexts. If you edit the question to describe more about the task you are facing, including that info from your comment, it will be much easier to know what type of answers you are seeking.

Comment: Still need to be more specific—what info about the topology do you want, precisely? "What direction it is flowing" doesn't help much.

Comment: i want information about the shape of the mesh so i can create a new mesh from that information with different geometry (but geometry with specific edges in specific places according to the shape of the mesh)

So in other words, i want geometry that follows the form of the mesh

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform curvature-aligned remeshing, see e.g. https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00099624, http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Yukun.Lai/papers/remesh_cad.pdf

Comment: Thanks Rahul! this is the first reply that has something to do with what i am looking for!